# Get list of users from SQL Anywhere v10+ without knowing password

Tags: sybase, sqlanywhere

I have a service that lets users upload small SQL Anywhere databases to my server and then query them later.

If possible, I'd like to be able to present the user a list of valid Usernames without the server needing to log in to the database to query the list of users.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. In order to list user names in a SQL Anywhere database, you need to be able to connect to the database while it's running.

*Full disclosure: I work for SAP in SQL Anywhere engineering.*